# HTML PHP Upload not uploading file

Tags: php, html, upload

Using HTML form to post a file to PHP and upload that file to a specified folder.

The PHP is returning 'Success' but the file has not been uploaded. The folder exists but no files upload.

`Q. Why is this file not being successfully uploaded?`

When error checking this line return an error

```
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
```

**The error**
Notice: Undefined index: files in scripts/uDoc.php on line 21 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in scripts/uDoc.php on line 21

**The HTML**

```
<form id='licenseForm' method='POST' action='scripts/uDoc.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='file' name="files" id='license_upload_btn' />
        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='{member_id}' />
        <input type='hidden' name='docType' value='license' />
</form>
```

**The PHP**

```
$errors= array();

foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];   


    $desired_dir="uDocs";

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"image_uploads/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="image_uploads/".$file_name.time();
            rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
    }else {
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: Look at `$desired_dir="uDocs";` and `image_uploads/` so, which folder do you want to use? You probably want something like `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"image_uploads/$desired_dir/".$file_name);` - hard to say though, but that's what I think you want to use.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: files in scripts/uDoc.php on line 21 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in scripts/uDoc.php on line 21

Comment: `$error` that variable is undefined in `if(empty($error)){`, so am sure you meant to use `if(empty($errors)){`

Comment: You also may want to move the brace `}` for the `foreach` after `$file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];` which is the one just above `if(empty($error)){` - It's taking everything inside that, as a `foreach` argument.

Comment: New Error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...on line 21

Comment: Did you base yourself on Example #1 on http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php by any chance?

Comment: i am trying to fix this for a friend who is not present but i believe it was yes.

Comment: Look at this line from the example: `foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {` Notice the `$error` variable and how it's used after in `if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {`? That's what you need to do also. Right now, your `$tmp_name` is taking the place of the `$error` in the example and is in limbo. Follow that example from the link above and you'll get it.

Comment: So try changing that to `foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $errors ){` and keeping the brace I asked you to move earlier, back to what it was.